# dash_bootstrap_components installed succesfully but no recognised

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I have my dash working perfectly. I have installed dash_bootstrap_components to give style to my dash.

I wrote `pip install dash-bootstrap-components` and was perfectly installed.

But when I run the app, I have this error:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_bootstrap_components'

I have:
dash-1.8.0
dash-bootstrap-components-0.8.2

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem, I tried to install by following the instructions on their website: https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/quickstart/

In the terminal command-line I typed the following:

```
pip install dash-bootstrap-components
```

I got the following error:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.

**To solve it**, you can do the following (the 1st one worked for me):

1) Install the package to the user folder:

```
python -m pip install --user dash-bootstrap-components
```

2) Setup a virtual env to install the package:

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate 
python -m pip install dash-bootstrap-components
```

3) Use sudo to install to the system folder **(not recommended)**:

```
sudo python -m pip install dash-bootstrap-components
```

After doing that it should work, **you can create a file with the following code and run the server to see if it works**:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    dbc.Alert("Hello Bootstrap!", color="success"),
    className="p-5",
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```