# dash-bootstrap-components not displaying dbc.Col / dbc.Row properly

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I tried to create columns block in dash app with code below:

```
import os
import sys
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
def init_dashboard(server):
    """Create a Plotly Dash dashboard."""
    dash_app = dash.Dash(
        __name__,
        external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
        meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width"}],
        server=server,
        routes_pathname_prefix="/distfinder/"
        
    )
    html_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'templates', 'dashapp.html')
    print(html_file_path)
    with open(html_file_path, 'r') as f:
        html_layout = f.read()
    dash_app.index_string = html_layout
    
    def serve_layout():
        html_element = html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.H1("Bootstrap Grid System Example")
                ,dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.Div(dbc.Alert("This is one column", color="primary"))))
                ,dbc.Row([
                        dbc.Col(html.Div(dbc.Alert("One of three columns", color="primary")))
                        ,dbc.Col(html.Div(dbc.Alert("One of three columns", color="primary")))
                        ,dbc.Col(html.Div(dbc.Alert("One of three columns", color="primary")))
                        ])
                    ])
        ])
        return html_element

    dash_app.layout = serve_layout
    return dash_app.server
```

However, I still receive the display like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4R8A.png)

I am building a dashapp which is nested in my flask website, and had to create a separate instance of Dash in one particular page, while the rest of the flask website runs through wsgi.py. The file structure looks something like below:

```
personal_website 
+--separate_dash_folder
|  |--dashboard.py <- where my dashapp reside
| 
+--static
|  |
|  +--css
|  +--js
|  +--files
|  +--fonts
|  +--img
|
+--templates
|  |
|  +--base.html
|  +--dashapp.html
|  +--home.html
|  \--the rest
|
+--flaskapp.py
+--wsgi.py
```

I went through a few stackoverflow questions but none of them seem to solve my problem.
[dash_bootstrap_components installed succesfully but no recognised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021936/dash-bootstrap-components-installed-succesfully-but-no-recognised)
[How to Fix My Plotly Dash App Not Organizing Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712079/how-to-fix-my-plotly-dash-app-not-organizing-properly)

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with my own source code, I realise that having non bootstrap CSS in the flask application for the dash_app.index_string (dashapp.html) will cause the dash_bootstrap_components to bug out.